# CVS add directory/ error "there is no version here; do `cvs checkout' first"

Tags: directory, addition, cvs

Using Terminal (on Mac OSX 10.8.x) whenever I try to add a directory within my project

```
project_root jacob$ cvs add foo/
project_root jacob$ cvs add ./shared/foo/
project_root jacob$ cvs add /full/path/foo/
```

CVS complains:

```
cvs add: in directory `.':
cvs [add aborted]: there is no version here; do `cvs checkout' first
```

Also, I've heard cvs does not like to create empty directories and it doesn't like to create a directory with only directories inside of it (no immediate children being files), so inside of `foo/` is just an empty file named `blank.txt`.

Running `cvs checkout project` does not help.

This message is ridiculous; obviously there is no version—that's why it's called `add`!

P.S. Upgrading to svn/Git is, sadly, not an option at this time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OMG, cvs is a terrible joke: the current working directory must be the immediate parent of the directory being added:

```
project_root jacob$ cd shared/
project_root jacob$ cvs add foo/
Directory /…/foo added to the repository
```

[source](http://drupal.org/node/353813#comment-1185079)

Comment: It didn't help, but CVS still sucks

Answer (score 0):

The parent folder needs to be added first into the repository. This is
a standard error message from cvs executable.

Comment: This should be added as comment, once you have enough reputation to do the same.